# Throttle round trip time on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, bandwidth, throttling

I test performance of a web application under different circumstances. I've learned how to throttle the bandwidth on Windows.

But i've got nowhere a possibility to setup the round trip time parameter for the network connection.

Could somebody point me how i setup custom round trip time for the network connection - for the *whole* Windows or certain application.

PS: yes, i know about browser developer tools, giving this possiblity in its throttling engine. But my tests doesn't run directly in a browser so i can't manage browser's own tools for this purpose.

Comment: How are your tests running? Can you not use a headless instance of Chrome/FF?

Comment: This is likely going to depend on the drivers and the options they allow to the OS. What are your system specs?

Comment: @music2myear i'm on ordinary win10x64 with ordinary hardware. I think rather in direction of a tool, a kind of middlware, to manage the connection. Maybe something like debugging proxy

Comment: We don't recommend software or hardware here, and questions seeking such recommendations are off topic.